# avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, vscode, sdk

estoy intentando correr una app de Hola mundo con flutter y visual studio code, he instalado andorid studio para obtener el sdk android.

El problema radica que cuando le intento crear un dispositivo virtual en el visual studio m dice que `avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK`, debo decir que estoy intentado usar el dispositivo que creé con android studio.

He visto en internet que el problema es que flutter no encuentra la ruta de mi sdk android. Intente la solución  de configurar la ruta mediante los comandos:

```
 flutter config --android-sdk /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk 
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Pero no me ha funcionado de hecho cuando ejecuto los comando, me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Pues ahí se está quejando en perfecto inglés porque no encuentra la versión de Java que necesita para ejecutarse, en esa ruta C/ProgramFiles/Android/jdk/... ¿ya la comprobaste?

Comment: La version de Java es el archivo Jdk??

Comment: acabo de verificar mi version de java y tengo instalada java version "1.8.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b108)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b50, mixed mode)... entonces como se supone que deba hacer para que encuentre la version de java

Comment: Probablemente sea porque no tienes un emulador creado, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Mira el mensaje de error y mira dónde está buscando. Está suponiendo que descargaste un Android Studio con Java "incluido" (bundled).

Ve a la configuración de ANdroid Studio y revisa lo que se muestra aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que te interesa es el tercer campo, JDK location.

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia amigo, ya encontré jdk location...que se supone q deba hacer ahora

Comment: Poner en ese campo la ruta al JDK que dices que está instalado